# removal of redundant lines based on value in last column

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I am trying to remove redundant data from my tab delimited file, which looks like this

```
chr1    1841    1851    4
chr1    1991    2001    3
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2501    2511    1
chr1    2681    2691    3
chr1    2881    2891    4
chr1    2891    2901    1
chr1    3241    3251    1
chr1    3241    3251    6
```

Condition is: if first three columns are same then the value in the fourth column (highest value) should be used to get the first three columns and also the fourth column. If there is a tie then only once the value in 4 columns should be printed.

So for the above input the ideal output should be

```
chr1    1841    1851    4
chr1    1991    2001    3
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2501    2511    1
chr1    2681    2691    3
chr1    2881    2891    4
chr1    2891    2901    1
chr1    3241    3251    6
```

How I approached:

sorted the file first and then I messed it

```
sort file | awk -F '\t' 'NR==1{last = $1; max = 0} {if (last != $1) {printf "%s\t%e\n", last, max; last = $1; max = $4} else if (max < $4) max = $4} END{printf "%s\t%e\n", last, max}'
```

Kindly help

Comment: The second to last line of the input was missing tab chars, maybe that is causing issues here.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sort -k1 -k2,3n -k4nr file | awk '!a[$1,$2,$3]++'
chr1    1841    1851    4
chr1    1991    2001    3
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2501    2511    1
chr1    2681    2691    3
chr1    2881    2891    4
chr1    2891    2901    1
chr1    3241    3251    6
```

Comment: When there are rows with duplicate columns 1-3, this uses the last one, not the one with the highest column 4.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be sorted first?

Comment: Yes, hence `sort file | awk ...` @Barmar where is requirement stated? Please fixed your own answer first as it doesn't not produce the expect output.

Comment: @Imagination it's not a typo, not sure I would call it a trick, just using concatenation of the first 3 fields as the key.

Comment: Requirement is stated in the question: _the fourth column (highest value) should be used_

Comment: I think you added the first `sort file` after I made my comment, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @sudo_O: Please check my output and you will find the difference between mine and yours :)

Comment: Is concatenation correct? What if one row has `chr1 34 5` and another row has `chr1 3 45`?

Comment: @Barmar your first comment says **not** the one with highest and your second comment says (higtest value) **should** be used. These contradict each other yes both have 3 upvotes, well done people!

Comment: No, my comment said that the original version of your script (before you added `sort`) did not use the highest value. I didn't say that it "should not" use the highest value.

Comment: The highest value should be used

Comment: @Imagination yes `$1$2$3` is what I thought I had, typo. Angelo the use the highest values, the file is sorted first and gives the expected output!?

Comment: @Barmar has a good point "What if one row has chr1 34 5 and another row has chr1 3 45?". You should use a[$1,$2,...] instead of a[$1$2...].

Comment: +1 for the approach but you need to specify numeric sorts on the 3 numeric fields. Try it with the 3rd input line populated as `chr1    2491    2501    12` instead of `chr1    2491    2501    2` and you'll see that "12" comes before "2" alphabetically instead of after "2" numerically as desired.

Comment: Beautiful. I'd give it another +1 if I could :-).

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton nice to have at least one sane user on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -k 1,3 -k 4r file | awk 'last != $1" "$2" "$3 { print; last = $1" "$2" "$3; }'
```

My output:

```
chr1    1841    1851    4
chr1    1991    2001    3
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2501    2511    1
chr1    2681    2691    3
chr1    2881    2891    4
chr1    2891    2901    1
chr1    3241    3251    6
```

http://ideone.com/nH6boE

Comment: One problem of the values where their is a tie in fourth column is solved like in case of line chr1    2491    2501 but the repetition of line is still present, where it should have opted for the highest value in fourth column like in line:  chr1    3241    3251

Comment: Fixed. `sort -u` can't work on only part of the key, so it does need awk.

Comment: Please check on the test data, it still doesn't work :( ... the repeated line in case of highest value in column 3 is still present it needs to be off from the data set

Comment: I did test it (I screwed up the first time, I tested it on the output instead of the input).

Comment: I still get these two line in out put chr1 3241 3251 6
chr1    3241    3251    1 instead of only this line chr1 3241 3251 6

Comment: I don't. I don't know what's different about our environments. Are you sure the file is delimited with tabs, not spaces?

Comment: There are spaces there, not tabs. I tested mine with a real file containing tabs, it works on both Linux and OS X.

Comment: I've removed `-F '\t'` from my command. Then it will work with any whitespace field separator.

Comment: No I don't. `print;` simply prints the original input, with deimiters intact.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using the first three columns as a key into a hash, and only remember the one with the largest `$4`:

```
<infile awk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

  $4 > h[$1,$2,$3] { h[$1,$2,$3] = $4 }

  END { 
    for(k in h) { 
      split(k, a, SUBSEP)
      print a[1], a[2], a[3], h[k]
    }
  }
' | sort -k1 -k2n,3n
```

Output:

```
chr1    1841    1851    4
chr1    1991    2001    3
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2501    2511    1
chr1    2681    2691    3
chr1    2881    2891    4
chr1    2891    2901    1
chr1    3241    3251    6
```

If you are using GNU awk you could also do the sorting from within awk:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }

$4 > h[$1,$2,$3] { h[$1,$2,$3] = $4 }

END { 
  len = asorti(h, d)
  for(i=1; i<=len; i++) {
    flen = split(d[i], a, SUBSEP)
    for(j=1; j<=flen; j++)
      printf "%s%s", a[j], OFS
    print h[d[i]]
  }
}
```

And run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Comment: @Angelo: which version doesn't work? What version of awk are you using?

Comment: awk version is 4.0.0, is this the problem ?

Comment: @Angelo: It works here. Maybe it's because I pass the file through `unexpand -a`?

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner should give the output:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{t=$1FS$2FS$3;if(!(t in a)||a[t]<$4)a[t]=$4}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' file|sort
```

clear format:

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{
    t=$1FS$2FS$3
    if(!(t in a)||a[t]<$4)
        a[t]=$4
 }
 END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' file|sort
```

if you run with your data file:

```
kent$  cat file
chr1    1841    1851    4
chr1    1991    2001    3
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2501    2511    1
chr1    2681    2691    3
chr1    2881    2891    4
chr1    2891    2901    1
chr1    3241    3251    1
chr1    3241    3251    6

kent$  awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{t=$1FS$2FS$3;if(!(t in a)||a[t]<$4)a[t]=$4}END{for(x in a) print x,a[x]}' file|sort
chr1    1841    1851    4
chr1    1991    2001    3
chr1    2491    2501    2
chr1    2501    2511    1
chr1    2681    2691    3
chr1    2881    2891    4
chr1    2891    2901    1
chr1    3241    3251    6
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. The output file still contains the repeated values. Look for the line chr1    3241    3251 , it is present two times instead of one time when it has a highest value of 6 in fourth column

Comment: @Angelo it won't. since in the array, the same index/key would be overwritten. see the output, I added in the answer.

Comment: I don't know why but I don't get the output as you get.And the problem is only with the line chr1    3241    3251, I get chr1    3241    3251   1  in fourth column instead of 6

Comment: @Angelo can you check if the line `3241 3251 1` in your real file is single tab-delimited? try to open your file in vim and execute this:`:%s/\s\+/\t/g` then try again.