# removal of lines based on category in a column

Tags: python, shell, awk

I am trying to remove lines in a comma delimited file where APPID are the same and the Category column are in the same category.  Input:

```
1,APPID,ID2,ID3,5,6,7,8,9,Category,
5002 , APP-1 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-1 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Biochemical ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
```

Ideal output:

```
1,APPID,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,Category ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Biochemical ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
```

"APP-1" is removed because their column 2 are the same and their Category column are all "Cell".

"APP-2" is kept because they have one "Cell" and the other one is "Biochemical" in its "Category" column.

The similar scenario in "APP-3" where its "Category" column contains heterogeneous categories.

(Updated) "APP-4" is kept because their column  contains heterogeneous categories.  We would like to keep the repetition of "    5002 , APP-4 ......", which will be taken care of in the next script.   This step is quickly removing tens of thousands of data points which are homogeneous in the "Category" column (if their APPID are the same) so that the array in the next script will not explode.

The attempt so far doesn't seem to work (reference from here: [removal of redundant lines based on value in last column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944392/removal-of-redundant-lines-based-on-value-in-last-column))

```
  awk -F " ," '!a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9]++' input
```

The process files are about million lines per files and in total about 400 files to process. The execute speed seems to be crucial here.  Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks!

Comment: What should happen if there are 3 repeats of an APP-ID and a category? What should happen if there are 3 occurrences of the same APP-ID, only two of which share the same category?

Answer (score 2):

```
def killDups(infilepath, outfilepath):
    data = {}
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        infile.readline()
        for i,line in enumerate(infile):
            line = line.strip()
            cols = [col.strip() for col in line.split(',')]
            appid, cat = cols[1], cols[-1]
            if appid not in data:
                data[appid] = {cat:i}
            elif cat in data[appid]:
                data[appid].pop(cat)

    whitelist = set()
    for k,v in data.items():
        whitelist.update(v.values())

    with open(infilepath) as infile, open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.readline())
        for i,line in enumerate(infile):
            if i in whitelist:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F, '
  { key=$2 FS $(NF-1); nr2key[NR]=key; key2val[key]=$0; cnt[key]++ }
  END {
      for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
          key=nr2key[i]
          if (cnt[key] == 1) {
              print key2val[key]
          }
      }
  }
  ' file
1,APPID,ID2,ID3,5,6,7,8,9,Category,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Biochemical ,
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! The script work perfectly. However, if I modify the input file slightly by including "5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Cell ," in the bottom, the script will only print out "5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Cell ," for APP-4 instead of printing out all the APP-4 ...Enzyme/Cell. May I know if you have any comment? Thanks. (I have updated the question.)

Comment: Next time you have a question, think a bit harder about the sample input and expected output so it represents all of the difficult/interesting combinations so we dont waste time solving the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
awk -F, '
!patt[$2,$(NF-1)]++ { lines[$2,$(NF-1)] = $0 } 
END {
    for (line in lines)
      if (patt[line] == 1)
        print lines[line]
}' file | sort -t, -nk1,2
1,APPID,ID2,ID3,5,6,7,8,9,Category,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Biochemical ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
```

- If two column are not in `patt` array assign entire line to lines array for same key
- In the `END` block iterate through lines array. If the key count from pattern array is 1, print the line.
- To sort the output pipe to sort.

**Note:** For a more elegant way using vanilla `awk` please refer [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173275/970195) solution.

if you have GNU `awk` then (similar logic but uses built in sorting algorithm):

```
gawk -F, '
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc" }
!patt[$2,$(NF-1)]++ {
    lines[$2,$(NF-1)] = $0
}
END {
    for (line in lines)
      if (patt[line] == 1)
        print lines[line]
}' file
```

if you can use `perl` then:

```
perl -F, -lane'                        
    print and next if $.==1;        # print the header
    $key = "@F[1,-1]";              # form the key using two columns
    $h{$key} or push @rec, $key;    # if key is not in hash push to array (for order)
    push @{$h{$key}}, $_            # create hash of arrays
}{                                  # In the END block ...
    print @{$h{$_}} for grep { @{$h{$_}} == 1 } @rec   # print line whose array count is 1
' file 
1,APPID,ID2,ID3,5,6,7,8,9,Category,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Biochemical ,
```

---

## **Update:**

```
perl -F, -lane'                        
    print and next if $.==1;       
    $seen{$F[1],$F[-1]}++ or push @rec, [$F[1], $F[-1]];    
    push @{$h{$F[1]}{$F[-1]}}, $_           
}{    
    for (@rec) {
        next if keys %{$h{$_->[0]}} == 1;
        print join "\n", @{$h{$_->[0]}{$_->[1]}};
    }
' file
1,APPID,ID2,ID3,5,6,7,8,9,Category,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Biochemical ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a GNU Awk solution that includes keys with overall heterogeneous values, which may contain duplicates, such as those in `APP-4`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
    OFS=","
}
{
    key[NR]=$2
    count[$2]++
    v=$(NF-1)
    val[NR]=v
    val_count[$2][v]++
    line[NR]=$0
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
        k=key[i]
        j=val[i]
        if(count[k] > 1) {
            if(val_count[k][j] == count[k]) {
                continue
            }else{
                print line[i]
            }
        }else{
            print line[i]
        }
    }
}
```

You can create this as an Awk file and name it something like `hetero.awk` and run the script from a shell like this:

```
gawk -f hetero.awk file
```

Output:

```
1,APPID,ID2,ID3,5,6,7,8,9,Category,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-2 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
5002 , APP-3 ,,,,,,,, Biochemical ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Enzyme ,
5002 , APP-4 ,,,,,,,, Cell ,
```

Or, for a dirtier approach you could just put the following in a shell script:

```
gawk -F, -v OFS=, '{
    key[NR]=$2
    count[$2]++
    v=$(NF-1)
    val[NR]=v
    val_count[$2][v]++
    line[NR]=$0
}END{
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
        k=key[i]
        j=val[i]
        if(count[k] > 1) {
            if(val_count[k][j] == count[k]) {
                continue
            }else{
                print line[i]
            }
        }else{
            print line[i]
        }
    }
}' file
```

As a general practice, I prefer to only use Awk one liners in my bash scripts.

Note that this utilizes arrays of arrays which is not a feature available in Awk variants such as mawk.

Comment: Thanks John.  Sorry I might not be familiar with gawk.  May I know how to execute it? I tried "sh test.sh" and "gawk -f test.gawk" and they both errors "awk: awk_test3.gawk:1:                ^ syntax error", etc.

Comment: The major error return is gawk -f gawk.sh "gawk: gawk.sh:1: gawk -F, '{      (change line)  gawk: gawk.sh:1:          ^ invalid char ''' in expression"